# Is it possible to use the PyPy interpreter in Spyder on Windows 10?

Tags: python, spyder, pypy

I'm looking to run pypy using spyder on Windows 10. I'm not sure if this is possible or even makes sense to do, but I'm used to using spyder to run python programs so I wanted to also use it to run pypy. I tried chaning the interpreter in  tools->preferences->python interpreter to C:/PyPy/pypy.exe but that gives me the warning that I selected an invalid python interpreter for the console. Any ideas on what else I need to do to make this possible? Any comments would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) This is not possible at moment, for the following reasons:

1. We require a Python interpreter and doesn't accept PyPy as an option in `Tools > Preferences > Python interpreter` (as you pointed out).
2. There are no [Pyzmq wheels](https://pypi.org/project/pyzmq/#files) for PyPy on Windows, only macOS. Pyzmq is the only binary package required to run Jupyter kernels (all the rest are pure Python), but without it our IPython consoles can't work.